# Get Google Drive folders for AdminDirectory.Activities.list events

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to see when a user last viewed/edited/created/deleted any file or files in specific Google Drive folders for the last 30 days.

I saw this documentation: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/reference/rest/v1/activities/list

I was able to create a script where I can get the event name (edit/create/etc), user email, time, etc for the past 30 days.

But I cannot figure out how to get what file or folder the activity was for. I cannot tell if the activity is for a specific Drive folder that I am checking activity for.

I found another option (https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2/reference/rest/v2/activity/query), where I can specify the Drive folder and see the activities, but as far as I can tell, this does have a 'view' activity.

I hope anyone can help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share more details on what you have tried and where you are lost?

Comment: I've tried the sample code here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive-activity. The other one I've tried uses AdminDirectory.Activities.list, and iterate items that it returns. The shortcomings of either options I've written in my original post. Basically I need to know the last time a user did something in a specific folder. This includes viewing, editing, creating, deleting files. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Btw, I'm in favor of using DriveActivity.Activity.query as it is more easier for what I need, it's just missing a 'view' event. Maybe there is a way to get that?

Comment: For viewing as you mentioned it needs to be fetched through the Reports Api? How about filtering the result from Activities: List by using the folder id on the response and then getting the last one?

Comment: I have not really 'found' the answer, but the best option for what I need is based on the example found here: [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-reports). Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Community Wiki from original poster comments:

I have not really 'found' the answer, but the best option for what I need is based on the example found here:

[Admin SDK Reports Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-reports)

Thanks again for your time